# angular: return array from object array properties

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I've got a 'user' object passed in when I load up a form, which I can use to directly populate my edit user form. So:

```
$scope.userData = getUserData();

<input id="uid" value="{{userData.uid}}"/>
<input id="name" value="{{userData.name}}"/>
```

My data looks like this:

```
userData = [{
    "empId":1,
    "name": "bob",
    "roles":[{
        "roleId":1,
        "title":"boss"
     },{
        "roleId":2,
        "title":"employee"
     }]
}]
```

I've got a custom control that wants the roles as a FLAT array of titles.

**So, this is what I'm hoping to produce:**

```
<sys-multi id="roles" options="['boss','employee']"></sys-multi>
```

The trick here is that I'm hoping to do this IN THE TEMPLATE, so no functions so my controller. i.e. something like this (if it worked):

```
<sys-multi id="roles" options="{{userData.roles.name.join(',')}}"></sys-multi>
```

I've been playing with grep, but angular doesn't like grep within its {{}}'s.

Comment: And why don't you want a controller function for this? Perhaps something that creates another key on your object with the flat array values? It'd be easy to do.

Comment: You should probably think about using a [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Comment: I was hoping to pass the array straight into the template. Looks like I'll have to grab it in the controller and massage it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about adding a getter (or a function) to your userData object:

```
$scope.userData = {
  "empId":1,
  "name": "bob",
  "roles":[{
     "roleId":1,
     "title":"boss"
  },{
     "roleId":2,
     "title":"employee"
  }],
  get roleNames() {
    return this.roles.map(function (role) {
      return role.title;
    });
  }
};
```

...and then using it this way:

```
<sys-multi id="roles" options="userData.roleNames"></sys-multi>
```

http://codepen.io/jlowcs/pen/emPKrB

Comment: Yes, it looks like I"ll be doing it in the controller.
I just used a method though:         var roleNames = $.map(userData.roles, function(role){ return role.id; });